# Processing variable data sets from responses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

**Case:** I collect customer orders using **Google Forms** platform. Each order consists of **variable** amount of positions, each position is presented with **constant** number of characteristics. At the moment my form has **1 contact data** section and **5** identical sections to fill **item information**.

---

Contact data section
[image]

---

Item 1 section
[image]

---

Item 2 section
[image]

---

For example, if you want to order **3** products, you'll have to skip **2** item sections in the form, and if you want to order **7** products - you must fill **2** forms (including the contact data), and skip **3** sections in the second form. After that each order will be stored in the **Google Sheet** as a very long row. It's uncomfortable and costly to manage the overall data in the sheet - the final order *"unwrapping"* takes a lot of time.

---

Order in the sheet
[image]

---

**Question #1:** Is there any way to implement the feature when the customer will see something like

- **1** item section and kind of *"Add one more item"* button that will attach a section with a set of characteristics (and maybe *"Remove item"* action)

*or*

- editable table with columns like *vendor code, size, color,* etc. So each order position will be represented with a row that can be added or removed.

**Question #2:** If it's possible, how should I program the data collection process to have the final **Google Sheet** with *"one position per row"* entries?

---

Regrouped order
[image]

---

Maybe there's some better ideas or solutions based on other configurable platforms that could fit the wishes given above.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @I'-'I there's no code yet, only out-of-the-box functionality's been used.

Comment: You're more likely to receive a answer, If you've researched extensively and    done your homework. Q1. In form settings, there's option to add another response after submitting. Use that. New responses will automatically be arranged row by row. You might wanna skip the contact data section. Use email-only to uniquely identify  customers. Alternatively, create a custom web-app to guide form flow.

Comment: The question is too broad as it include several questions on it and it doesn't include a brief description of your search/research efforts. By the other it's also primarily opinion based as there are several ways "to design the solution" (besides the idea shared on the previous comment, you could use a drop-down question at the end of each section with an option to continue to the next section and another to submit the form)

Comment: @I'-'I Well, the research haven't brought something helpful. As I described in my question - customers submit several responses if they want to order more items than one form contains. The problem is in the way the data is being collected and stored - the sheet contents is too cluttered and heterogeneous. I've planned to develop the Java app that would transform the sheet with responses to correct and clear view, but this will involve a lot of checks just to find and collect the whole set of order items in a huge sheet for each customer.

Comment: @Rubén I would like to customize the purchasing process to make it more flexible like you simply fill one Form with information about products you want (no matter 1 item or 10, it's up to you) and, it it's possible, this order will be stored in the sheet line by line like it's shown in the screenshot above. Of course, standard functionality doesn't offer something straight for this, but maybe some scripts or tweaks that I'm not familiar with could help. Please correct me if I'm wrong - you mean that I can program the behavior of the drop-down question to generate a new section?

Comment: Yup It's work to create a  google apps script web-app. But  that's the cost of customization. Alternatively, You can use the `onFormSubmit` trigger to arrange items on sheet. This is lesser work. There are multiple options.

Comment: @I'-'I That's a good cost) I mean, is it technically possible to step into the data collection and handling process so I could customize the Form representation and the way the Sheet is being populated with order information? In other words, there's some event handler that can catch the data at form submission and store it in the Sheet after some transformations.

Comment: Like I said, there's `onFormSubmit` trigger. It catches the data, but the sheet will already be modified...But, You can change the sheet data in the same handler. Trigger>getSheet>Arrange Data. or If you don't have a direct link to sheet, Trigger> getSheet>Add new data in order.

Comment: @I'-'I will try that) Thank you so much for help and clarification!